# Global Array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, global-variables

just wondering, how do you use global arrays of a structure's?

For example:

```
int y = 0;
object objectArray [100];

typedef struct object{
    time_t objectTime;
    int objectNumber;
} object;

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        time_t time_now;
        time_now = time(NULL);

        object x = {time_now, objectNo}
        objectArray[y] = x;
        y++;

    }
}
```

This always throws an "error: array type has incomplete element type", can anybody advise me of the problem and an appropriate solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the definition of the struct to before your declaration of the array:

```
typedef struct object{
    time_t objectTime;
    int objectNumber;
} object;

object objectArray [100];
```

You're getting that error because the compiler doesn't know the size of `object` when it gets to the array declaration.